# RE-Intel 82759LM Not working Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, ethernet

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on my desktop. My ethernet card is the intel 82759LM. However when I try to use it on my lenovo m82 SFF PC, it registers on the router as being connected and lights up on the ethernet outlet on my pc. However it does not show up in Ubuntu or Windows10. Can someone please help me?

Comment: What do you mean it does not show up. More details please and what troubleshooting have you done?